3ddv Venue Map issue
I am trying to make the map layout so that it is not cut off when I reduce the width.
In the examples in the doc, the map is cut off in all of them and is not made responsive.
I saw a behavior with the management of the stadiums, for example, the Camp Nou that handles the issue of responsiveness very well.
Any idea how to handle it?
https://docs.3ddvapis.com/js/dvm/modules/map_viewer/examples/loading-a-map/
I tried to simulate it by adding the same wrappers with the styles but it also got complicated.
https://3ddigitalvenue.com/3dmap/clients/fcbarcelona/
I am not sure how the following code can help, but just in case I share it:

// Loading MAP ...

useEffect(() => {
    if (mapType === "2d" && !hasLoadedRef.current) {
      hasLoadedRef.current = true;

      const loadMap = async () => {
        if (!containerRef.current || viewerRef.current) return;

        try {
          const viewer = await loadModule("map_viewer", {
            container: containerRef.current,
          });
          viewerRef.current = viewer;

          const venue = await viewer.loadMap({
            venue_id: "nam-us-10229-chiefs-sec",
          });
          console.log("Viewer loaded:", viewer);
          console.log("Venue loaded:", venue);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error loading the map viewer:", error);
        }
      };

      loadMap();
    }

    return () => {
      if (viewerRef.current) {
        viewerRef.current.reset();
        viewerRef.current = null;
      }
    };
  }, [mapType]);
  // rendering Map
  return (
    <>
      {mapType === "2d" && (
            <div ref={containerRef} />
      )}
    </>
  );

